# Sugarcrm DCMenu Qucik Create | After Save redirect

Tags: redirect, sugarcrm

I am showing quick create view of a custom Module Payment on a Button Click in the `detail View of Accounts via DC menu load view in SugarCRM.`
what i want is when i save values on clicking the save button for the QuickCreate View, i want to redirect the user to the newly created record.

In the after save logic hook for the payments module i have tries all these

1) Used JavaScript `window.location.href` for redirection

2) `SugarApplication::redirect()`;

3) Changed values of `$_POST['return_module']`, `$_POST['return_action']` and `$_POST['return_id']`

Yet after applying all of the Above in a correct way the page does not redirect. I am using `AJAX UI` for the Accounts Module.

Comment: Which version of Sugar is this for?

Comment: SugarPRO Version 6.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a workaround which is obviously not upgrade safe but does the trick.

what i did is created a logic hook on after_save for the CustomModule and indexed it to a bigger number like

```
$hook_array['after_save'][] = array(20,
```

In that hook after my custom logic finished i checked for the AJAX Call and finished the process like this

```
if($_REQUEST['is_ajax_call'] == 1)
{
    echo '{"status":"redirect","url":"index.php?module=lev_payment_schedules&action=DetailView&record='.$bean->id.'&CreatePayment=true"}';
    die();
}
```

Now in the DCMenu.js file located at

> jssource\src_files\include\DashletContainer\Containers\DCMenu.js

i added a condition for the output i just echoed above.

In `DCMenu.save` function just in the `switch ( returnData.status )` Block i added my custom case condition as

```
case 'redirect':                                
    ajaxStatus.flashStatus(SUGAR.language.get('app_strings','LBL_SAVED'),2000);
    window.location.href = returnData.url;                              
   break;
```

This did the trick for me and the browser was redirected to the URL that i had supplied. i hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this customization http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Customization/Modifying_Subpanel_Action_Buttons to redirect your user on full form instead of quick create, your code describe above should probably works.